# plotting tree with networkx at colab

Tags: plot, networkx, google-colaboratory

I have graph, represented as nodes, edges and labels for the nodes, denoted as [nodes, edges, labels]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1000, linewidths=3)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels)
plt.show()
```

what i get when i run it on colab is this mess:

[image]

I need it to be a tree, with the root (pos) at the top, and the text to be read-able. 
Also, I'm using Colab, so pygraphviz is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to use `pygraphviz` in Colab

```py
!apt install libgraphviz-dev
!pip install pygraphviz
import pygraphviz as pgv
```

Here's an [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xU5CPcUMb7u88QROCIU4Nx6ftfmgZ0zE?usp=sharing).

For me, I prefer `pyvis` because you can drag the nodes around. Here's an example how to use `pyvis` with networkx: [networkx pyvis.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F_9BqVAXze6T9U7cj5BsrkyfzaoYnCc6?usp=sharing)